# Deleting a Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Basically, I just want to obliterate my entire database and create a new one. How do I actually do that, in explicit steps?

Comment: `drop database <name>;create database <newDBName>;`? what's with the username lol

Comment: where do i type that? (im working in android studio)

Comment: @Chris: There is no `drop database` command in SQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a user, you can:

- Uninstall the app, the way you would uninstall any other app (e.g., Settings > Apps > (the app's page) > Uninstall).
- Clear the data of the app (e.g., Settings > Apps > (the app's page) > Clear data or  Settings > Apps > (the app's page) > Storage > Clear data)

As a developer, manually, you can:

- Uninstall the app, using `adb uninstall your.package.name.here`, where `adb` is located in the `platform-tools/` directory of your Android SDK, and where `your.package.name.here` is your `applicationId` (if you specified that in `build.gradle`) or your `package` value on the `<manifest>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file
- Clear the data of the app, using `adb shell pm clear your.package.name.here` (see previous bullet for details of `adb` and `your.package.name.here`)

As a developer, programmatically, you can call `deleteDatabase()` on any `Context` (e.g., an `Activity`), passing in the name of your database.

Comment: where do I know the name of my database? all i know is the name of the tables i want to add

Comment: @stackoverflow_sucks: "where do I know the name of my database?" -- you chose it when you created it, via `SQLiteOpenHelper`, `createDatabase()`, etc.

Comment: i wound up finding it. i just changed the name of the database, and thereby effectively created a new one. the ghost of the old one may still haunt me, but it's just a ghost now. thanks for your help